# Conditional IF in T-SQL Errors?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this stored procdure

```
CREATE PROC dob.p_foobar
(
  @foo bit = NULL,
  @Bar bit = NULL
)

AS

IF @Foo == 1
BEGIN
   SELECT 'Hello, World'
END
```

When I parse, I get the error "Incorrect syntax near '='".

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I know it's something stupid, but I just can't figure it out.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL uses a single equals sign (=), not a double equals sign (==)

Answer (score 1):

No ==

```
IF @Foo = 1
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

Comment: No `THEN` :) I regularly make that mistake myself :(